# Vue - v-model inside a component within a component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to separate my project now into components to make the code readable when adjusting into a responsive app. The problem is passing the `v-model` from base-select -> child -> parent. How do I store the data selected to the `Parent.vue` `items: ''`? Here is my code below.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <child></child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './components/Child'

export default {
  components: { 
    Child,
  },
  data: ()=> ({
    item: ''
  })
}
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  // Random HTML
  // Random HTML 2
  <base-select 
  :items="select"
  >
</template>

<script>
import BaseSelect from '@/components/BaseSelect'

export default {
  components: { 
    BaseSelect,
  },
  data: ()=> ({
    select: ['Select 1', 'Select 2']
  })
}
</script>
```

**BaseSelect.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-select
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    class="body-2"
    solo
    dense
    clearable
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement `v-model` you need to add a `value` property to each child component. Each component will also need to emit an `input` event so that the parent component can pick up the change (read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)). Note that if you are passing data down through too many components, you should probably look at using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) however in this case it would probably still be fine.

Your components would have to look something like this to pass v-model all the way to the base component:

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <!-- Pass the data item below -->
  <child v-model="item"></child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './components/Child'

export default {
  components: { 
    Child,
  },
  data: ()=> ({
    item: ''
  })
}
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  // Random HTML
  // Random HTML 2
  <base-select 
    :items="select"
    value="value"
    @input="e => $emit('input', e)"
  >
</template>

<script>
import BaseSelect from '@/components/BaseSelect'

export default {
  components: { 
    BaseSelect,
  },
  // We add the value prop below to work with v-model
  props: {
    value: String
  },
  data: ()=> ({
    select: ['Select 1', 'Select 2']
  }),
}
</script>
```

**BaseSelect.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-select
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    value="value"
    @input="e => $emit('input', e)"
    class="body-2"
    solo
    dense
    clearable
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: String
  }
}
</script>
```

You can find a similar working example that I did [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-v-model-multiple-children-lre7h).

Comment: It looks more complicated passing from components to components. Yeah, like what @dreyhiflden have said, you're right vuex makes it more simple.

Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $emit ([documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)) to passing data back to parent components. Or you can start using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) (state manager for Vue.js).

You also can check the live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-select-props-demonstration-900p6).

Comment: I totally forgot about vuex. I have this principle of using vuex the least possible and contain methods within components. I'll go read the documentation and if ever I fail to implement it, I'll go with vuex. Thanks man!